# A way to configure WebSphere 8.5 Liberty Profile programmatically?

Tags: websphere-8, wsadmin, websphere-liberty

I'm moving from IBM RAD 8 / WAS 7.0 to IBM RAD 9 / WAS 8.5. Liberty Profile. There's a plenty of configuration things such as URLs and namespace bindings.

I've found an information that [WSADMIN is not working for Liberty Profile](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_scriptingep.html). I haven't found, however, the information, how to access similar functionality as in wsadmin/jython, for example for creating URLs, namespace bindings, etc.?

How to script such things under WebSphere Liberty Profile?

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to address a few things that are implied by your use of wsadmin. I may be overshooting, but I hope this helps:

WSADMIN applies only to the full WebSphere Application Server. jython scripting for the Liberty profile is possible, though you're basically performing JMX operations on a server. Here is something to get started with: https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/docs/creating-remote-jmx-connections-with-jython/

There is no way to reconfigure a Liberty profile server via a JMX operation, however. All server configuration (or reconfiguration) is done by editing the server configuration file (either manually with an editor of your choice, via the eclipse tools, or with a script that modifies your XML).

The Liberty profile does not support CORBA or CORBA namespaces (corbaloc or corbaname), or remote EJBs. Liberty profile servers also are not part of the cell/node topology of full profile servers. Instead, Liberty profile servers form collectives, as described here: 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/cwlp_collective_arch.html

You can add strings to JNDI using the jndiEntry element in your server configuration as described here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jndi.html

Information about configuring datasources (I am guessing at what you might need URLs and namespace bindings for) is here (see also the subtopics): http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the links in this answer are now out of date.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to edit the XML directly or using a script in the language of your choice. The idea is that the config is simple enough wsadmin is no longer needed - it's intended to be human readable and human maintainable. You can import XML snippets if you have repeated config elements you want to share similar elements across multiple servers, or create the same config elements multiple times.

Comment: I've searched "WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile Guide for Developers" and "WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Administration and Configuration Guide for Liberty profile" books from IBM but I haven't found any info how to configure URL resource and namespace binding there (I was looking for string 'namespace binding')